# Background service without notification

Tags: android, android-service

I understand why we have foreground services, we can for example play music or download something in the background and still inform user what is happening.
But I see no reason for existing background services without notification. I think user should be always aware about progress in the background.

What are the example uses of background services without UI in real industry ?

Comment: Take Gmail app if you keep sync on it will be in the background and notify you whenever you get an Email. Gmail won't notify you every moment that Gmail is syncing but it will notify you when you receive an Email

Comment: Nice, but it finally notice user when we got an email, so background can show notification? I thought only foreground can show notification.

Comment: well, a use case can be caching data server data into an app database even if a user is not in the same activity,  It doesn't make sense for showing a notification to the user about what work are we doing in the background.

Comment: "Gmail app if you keep sync on it will be in the background and notify you whenever you get an Email" -- most likely, Gmail is using Firebase Cloud Messaging (or Google proprietary equivalents), not a continuously-operating background service. "What are the example uses of background services without UI in real industry ?" -- there are none on modern versions of Android, as a background service can only run for one minute.

Comment: if we have only 1 minute for background service, how it is possible to receive notifications from apps ? I've got notifications from turned off applications all day?